# copy field value to text file and save as .sql

Tags: vba, ms-access, vbscript

in MS Access i have a field that stores the SQL used for a project. the sql field is a memo field with "Rich Text" property enabled. what that means is that a code below

```
CREATE TABLE NR_TMP_1_104 AS
     SELECT DISTINCT tmp.otherid
                    ,tmp.groupno
       FROM NR_tmp_1_900 tmp
           ,NR_TMP_1_103 vp
      WHERE tmp.otherid = vp.otherid;



      SELECT groupno, COUNT(otherid) Counts
      FROM NR_TMP_1_104
      GROUP BY groupno;

     SELECT otherid, actualvpchoice FROM NR_TMP_2_102
```

really looks like all the way below (i'm sorry for this huge chunk). so that means i can't do docmd.transfertext, the only way to get normal looking text is to copy and paste.

i need to be able to export this field to a text file and save it with the extension of .sql.

here's what i have so far))))

```
Forms!freports!sql.SetFocus
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
```

how do i open a text file, paste what's on my clipboard and save it as .sql.

thank you very much

```
"<div>&nbsp;</div>

<div><font size=3 color=blue style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">CREATE</font><font
size=3 color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF""> </font><font size=3
color=blue style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">TABLE</font><font size=3
color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF""> </font><font size=3 color=olive
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">NR_TMP_1_104</font><font size=3 color=black
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF""> </font><font size=3 color=blue
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">AS</font></div>

<div><font size=3 color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><font
size=3 color=blue style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">SELECT</font><font size=3
color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF""> </font><font size=3 color=blue
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">DISTINCT</font><font size=3 color=black
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF""> tmp</font><font size=3 color=blue
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">.</font><font size=3 color=black
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">otherid</font></div>

<div><font size=3 color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><font
size=3 color=blue style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">,</font><font size=3
color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">tmp</font><font size=3 color=blue
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">.</font><font size=3 color=black
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">groupno</font></div>

<div><font size=3 color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><font
size=3 color=blue style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">FROM</font><font size=3
color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF""> NR_tmp_1_900 tmp</font></div>

<div><font size=3 color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><font
size=3 color=blue style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">,</font><font size=3
color=olive style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">NR_TMP_1_103</font><font size=3
color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF""> vp</font></div>

<div><font size=3 color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><font
size=3 color=blue style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">WHERE</font><font size=3
color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF""> tmp</font><font size=3
color=blue style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">.</font><font size=3 color=black
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">otherid </font><font size=3 color=blue
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">=</font><font size=3 color=black
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF""> vp</font><font size=3 color=blue
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">.</font><font size=3 color=black
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">otherid</font><font size=3 color=blue
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">;</font></div>

<div><font size=3 color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></div>

<div><font size=3 color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></div>

<div><font size=3 color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></div>

<div><font size=3 color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><font
size=3 color=blue style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">SELECT</font><font size=3
color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF""> groupno</font><font size=3
color=blue style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">,</font><font size=3 color=black
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF""> </font><font size=3 color=blue
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">COUNT(</font><font size=3 color=black
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">otherid</font><font size=3 color=blue
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">)</font><font size=3 color=black
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF""> Counts</font></div>

<div><font size=3 color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><font
size=3 color=blue style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">FROM</font><font size=3
color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF""> </font><font size=3 color=olive
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">NR_TMP_1_104</font></div>

<div><font size=3 color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><font
size=3 color=blue style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">GROUP</font><font size=3
color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF""> </font><font size=3 color=blue
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">BY</font><font size=3 color=black
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF""> groupno</font><font size=3 color=blue
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">;</font></div>

<div><font size=3 color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></div>

<div><font size=3 color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><font
size=3 color=blue style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">SELECT</font><font size=3
color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF""> otherid</font><font size=3
color=blue style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">,</font><font size=3 color=black
style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF""> actualvpchoice </font><font size=3
color=blue style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF"">FROM</font><font size=3
color=black style=""BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF""> NR_TMP_2_102</font></div>"
```

Comment: Are you trying to save it programmability, or do you just want to open notepad, paste, and save as .sql?

Comment: programmatically. but i want to do exactly what you said, open notepad, paste and save as sql, not export from access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `PlainText()` function to get just the plain text from your memo field's rich text.  Here's an example from the Immediate window.

```
? DLookup("memo_field", "tblFoo", "id=1")
<div>a <strong>b </strong>c</div>

? PlainText(DLookup("memo_field", "tblFoo", "id=1"))
a b c
```

Once you get the plain text, you don't need to go through Notepad in order to write it to a file.  You can write to a file directly using VBA file functions or via the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` methods.  Here is an example of the first approach.  (I'm assuming `Forms!freports!sql` contains the rich text.)

```
Dim FileNum As Integer
FileNum = FreeFile()
Open "C:\SomeFolder\your.sql" For Output As #FileNum
Write #FileNum, PlainText(Forms!freports!sql)
Close #FileNum
```

Comment: i knew you were coming to this topic)))) you are amazing, your knowledge in vba and vbs is amazing. and so is your patience. i really appreciate everything you've helped me with. thank you!!!!

Comment: tiny problem. the sql in the file is surrounded by quotes. not a huge deal but that kills the formatting in notepad++. any idea why it's doing it?

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe strip them out when you write `PlainText(Forms!freports!sql)`?  If it's a single double quote at the start and another at the end ... `strTemp = PlainText(Forms!freports!sql)` then write `Mid(strTemp, 2, Len(strTemp) -2)` ... off the top of my head.

Comment: no, it's hidden in a way. the quotes don't show up in a msgbox or debug.print, but they get written to the file. so i had to use the clipboard after all. your solution still led me on the right path so i stand by everything i said

Answer (score 1):

just for reference, if anyone ever needs it. HansUp's code works fine and doesn't use any references (the code below needs MS Forms reference) and is just overall a much better coding example.

however, if anyone needs the quotes removed then here's one way of doing it.

```
Dim objFSO
Dim objFile
Dim ClipboardText

Me.sql.SetFocus
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy


Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject

 DataObj.GetFromClipboard
 ClipboardText = DataObj.GetText



Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\mysql.sql", 2, True)
objFile.WriteLine ClipboardText
objFile.Close
```